# Sort grid using memory table

Tags: delphi

I want to sort a grid. I created a memory table and link it to the grid as the data source.I am inserting data to the memory table from a nxQuery object. For the sorting i have to add index as well to the memory table.

This is the index adding and inserting part which is in the form create event

```
nxMemTable1.IndexDefs.Clear;
nxMemTable1.FieldDefs.Clear;

nxMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('packpatientid', ftInteger, 0, False);
nxMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('firstname', ftString, 10, False);
nxMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('lastname', ftString, 10, False);
while not nxQuery1.EOF do
begin
  nxMemTable1.Append;
  nxMemTable1.FieldByName('packpatientid').AsInteger :=   nxQuery1packpatientid.AsInteger;
  nxMemTable1.FieldByName('firstname').AsString := nxQuery1firstname.AsString;
  nxMemTable1.FieldByName('lastname').AsString := nxQuery1lastname.AsString;
  nxMemTable1.Post;
end;
```

and this is the code that i am trying to sort the memory table

`procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  nxMemTable1.IndexFieldNames := 'firstname';
end;`

but this is not working. when i click the button it says "No index for field 'firstname'"

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2350500/5470883

Comment: On the face of it, the assignment to nxMemTable1.IndexFieldNames should work.  If it doesn't then I think you need to ask nxMemTable1's authour, because it looks like a bug.  Make an example that creates the data in code rather than copies it from another dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works with the standard *TClientDataSet*.

I created a new VCL Forms project, dropped a *TClientDataSet* on the form, and named it `CDS` for simplicity in the code. I then added a *TDataSource*, assigned `CDS` to its *DataSet* property, added a *TDBGrid*, and assigned `DataSet1` as its *DataSource*. I then created two event handlers, one for the `Form1.OnCreate` event and one for the `DBGrid1. OnTitleClick` event.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var
  sField: string;
begin
  sField := Column.FieldName;
  if sField <> CDS.IndexFieldNames then
    CDS.IndexFieldNames := sField;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CDS.FieldDefs.Add('LastName', ftString, 30);
  CDS.FieldDefs.Add('FirstName', ftString, 30);
  CDS.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger);
  CDS.CreateDataSet;
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Smith', 'John', 3]);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Doe', 'Jane', 1]);
  CDS.AppendRecord(['Adams', 'Quincy', 2]);
  CDS.IndexFieldNames := 'LastName';
end;
```

Running the application and clicking on any of the column titles immediately sorts the DBGrid by that column (if it's not already sorted by that column).